# PHP whitespace before and after a given string need to be considered for byte processing

Tags: php, sockets, whitespace

I need to send 8 bytes to a given server in my socket.

The string should have 8 bytes with 3 characters and 5 empty spaces. However, `PHP` always strips out the spaces. How could i go about this?

```
<?php
   $SERVICE_NAME = "PXA     "; //8 bytes
   $OPT = "CODE5";

   $sendBytes = $SERVICE_NAME . $OPT;

   //i need sendBytes to go as PXA     CODE5
   //instead it goes as PXA CODE5.     

   $mySocket->send($sendBytes);
?>
```

Comment: php doesn't strip spaces. `strlen($sendBytes)` should return 13. show what this `$mySocket` class is doing...

Comment: php shouldn't trim the space untill u use a `trim($string)` function. Are u using the function anywhere?

Comment: It is stripping them and i am  getting just PXA CODE5,strangely when i say view source,then it is not stripped,but in the send method,space is stripped

Comment: output from the above source with a simple  -> echo $sendBytes; is showing PXA CODE5 . But when i say view source,then the spaces are showing correctly,however from the send method for the socket, it has no space and hence is not working.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're describing that it is displaying in the web page without the extra spaces, which is normal behavior. What happens if you wrap it with `<pre></pre>` tags?

Comment: wrapping it in the pre tags shows the desired output,the trouble is when i put directly as "PXA{with 5 spaces}CODE5",it works.. but after doing the appending for sendBytes, the socket server returns invalid length.

Comment: both service name and options come in dynamically by the way

Comment: You say the server is expecting 8 bytes, correct? However, your string `$SERVICE_NAME` is already 8 bytes and then you're adding 5 more bytes when you add `$OPT`. So you're sending 13 bytes when it's expecting 8. Are you sure you don't want the characters from `$OPT` to replace the spaces in `$SERVICE_NAME`?